# What is APSProtocolMessageTimestamp in IOS persistent log?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

When i push some message to my iphone.

I got some log like this:

```
2015-05-18 20:41:47 +0800 apsd[89]: <APSCourier: 0x13ed08360>: Stream processing: complete yes, invalid no, length parsed 303, parameters {
    APSProtocolBaseToken = <>;
    APSProtocolCommand = 10;
    APSProtocolMessageExpiry = "2015-05-19 12:33:52 +0000";
    APSProtocolMessageID = <00000014>;
    APSProtocolMessageStorageFlags = 1;
    APSProtocolMessageTimestamp = 48952622209358680;
    APSProtocolPayload = <>;
    APSProtocolToken = <>;
    APSProtocolTopicHash = <>;
}
```

Clearly the APSProtocolMessageTimestamp is illegal. Is there some docs about what the APSProtocolMessageTimestamp means and is there any wrong in my server program?